# Variable scope inside constructor

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, functions can always access global variables.  I have a class that I am using, and it references global variables.  Here's a similar class:

```
function Test(){
    this.abc = abc;
}
```

If I set the global `abc` then call this, it works.

```
var abc = 123,
    testA = new Test;

console.log(testA.abc); // 123
```

But what if I don't want `abc` to be global?  I wrapped the code in a function call, but I get an error saying `abc is not defined`.

```
(function(){
    var abc = 123,
        testA = new Test;  // ERROR: abc is not defined

    console.log(testA.abc);
})();
```

How can I read local variables inside a JavaScript constructor without adding variables to the global scope?

Comment: Why not pass `abc` as a parameter to `Test(.)`?

Comment: @mbratch: Because I didn't write `Test`.  I was just wondering if I could "fix" it without re-writing. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that local variables have *lexical* scope.

That means that to be resolved they must be within the same code block, or in *enclosing* code blocks.

Your code would only work if the definition of `Test` was also within the IIFE:

```
(function(){
    var abc = 123,
        testA = new Test;  // ERROR: abc is undefined

    function Test() {      // this will be hoisted
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    console.log(testA.abc);
})();
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid there was no way around this.

Comment: so you're trying to make `Test` work without rewriting it, but referring to a local variable instead of global?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.  `Test` was written by someone else, and relies on global variables (for whatever reason).  I hate global variables and was wondering if I avoid them.

Comment: You _might_ be able to make it work using `with`, but that'll probably cause more problems than it fixes.  It's also not allowed in ES5 "strict" mode.

Comment: I thought of `with`, but I am using `'use strict';` on my code :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat that's good ;)  I don't know of any other workaround.

Comment: That's fine.  I didn't think there was one, but might as well ask :)

Comment: Oddly enough, `with` doesn't seem to work here!  Unless I did something wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/kVDKn/